# How can I convert a list to float inside a for statement

Tags: python

I have multiple lists of numerators and denominators that I'm counting as I parse through a site to get variables that I want to turn into fractions. (eg. a = [1, 2] should be converted to a = 0.5).

I've tried this:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 5]

for i in a, b:
  i = i[0]/i[1]
  print(i)

print(a, b)
```

and I get:

```
>>> 0.5
>>> 0.6
>>> [1, 2] [3, 5]
```

The variables return the output I'm looking for when printed inside the for statement but not outside. How can I fix this? For loop isn't necessary, if there's an easier way to do it I'm all ears.

(I'm using Python 3.10)

@Eli Harold:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1, 4]
>>> for i in a, b:
...     i = i[0]/i[1]
... 
>>> print(a)
[1, 2]
>>> print(b)
[1, 4]
```

Comment: Please show an example of the unwated result and the code from "printing outside the loop".

Comment: Edited the post @EliHarold

Comment: You are printing a and b, not a/b. use: `print([i/j for i,j in [a,b])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
c = [ n/d for n,d in [a,b] ] 

print(c)
[0.5, 0.6]
```

- `for ... in [a,b]` will iterate through each list one by one
- `n,d` will be unpacked from the first and second item of each list
- `[ n/d ... ]` build a resulting list with each `n` and `d` provided by the `for`

you could assign the result to the original variables if needed:

```
a,b = ( n/d for n,d in [a,b] ) 

print(a,b)
0.5 0.6
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use list comprehension. You will be able to store your results in a list and get them by list indexing. For example:

```
result = [x/y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```